# Cannot install RubyGems 2.0.0 because 'cannot load such file -- openssl (LoadError)'

Tags: rubygems, openssl

I am trying to setup rails on a new machine and am having problems setting up RubyGems. due to the error in the question.  When checking `openssl version` I get: OpenSSL 0.9.8r 8 Feb 2011

I should also note, that currently, openssl.cnf can be found in $HOME/.rvm/usr/ssl

showing that it is installed.  I have tried reinstall ruby 2.0.0 in the following way:

```
rvm reinstall 2.0.0 --with-openssl-dir=$HOME/usr/local
```

I get a couple of errors here, including the following reference to /Users/me/.rvm/log/ruby-2.0.0-p0/configure.log:

```
[2013-02-27 10:34:16] ./Configure
Usage: Configure [no-<cipher> ...] [enable-<cipher> ...] [experimental-<cipher> ...]
[-Dxxx] [-lxxx] [-Lxxx] [-fxxx] [-Kxxx] [no-hw-xxx|no-hw] [[no-]threads] [[no-]shared]      
[[no-    ]zlib|zlib-dynamic] [no-asm] [no-dso] [no-krb5] [sctp] [386] [--prefix=DIR] 
[--openssldir=OPENSSLDIR] [--with-xxx[=vvv]] [--test-sanity] os/compiler[:flags]
```

And here in /Users/me/.rvm/log/ruby-2.0.0-p0/openssl/make.log:

```
making all in crypto/des...
cc -I.. -I../.. -I../modes -I../asn1 -I../evp -I../../include  -O   -c -o set_key.o 
set_key.c
set_key.c: In function ‘DES_set_key_unchecked’:
set_key.c:399: error: unsupported inline asm: input constraint with a matching output     
constraint of incompatible type!
set_key.c:402: error: unsupported inline asm: input constraint with a matching output  
constraint of incompatible type!
make[2]: *** [set_key.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [subdirs] Error 1
make: *** [build_crypto] Error 1
```

I've been pulling my hair out for a day over this.  What am I missing?

Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing

```
rvm reinstall 2.0.0 --with-openssl-dir=$HOME/usr/local
```

with

```
rvm reinstall 2.0.0 --with-openssl-dir=$HOME/.rvm/usr/ssl
```

Given that you are saying that your openssl config file is sitting there.

Answer (score 1):

I tried "Option 1" in the following gist and it worked for me.

https://gist.github.com/jfirebaugh/4007524